# Nodejs having routing issue using slash

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using handlebars not jade for routing but I think this issue I face not tied to handlebars but general routing issue with nodejs.

In app.js I have these

```
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.use('/catalog', require('./routes/catalog'));
```

Then in the routes folder I have a folder call catalog and within it I have catalog.js.

In catalog.js I do

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = module.exports = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('catalog/index');
});
```

It worked fine when I go to http://localhost:3000/catalog but it excluded from the layout when I try to run http://localhost:3000/catalog/ Any idea why?

Comment: In Node routes are quite litteral, so `/catalog` does not match `/catalog/`, there is however middleware that solves that, for instance [**connect-slashes**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-slashes)

Comment: @adeneo I used that, it automatically added a slash to the end, but it broke everything. I'm getting a not found for that.

Comment: Yes, it can be tricky, but you either have to write your own middleware, use something that is ready made, or use two routes, Express doesn't catch both `/catalog` and `/catalog/`, or it actually does, it just sees them as two different URL's

Comment: so ignore the slash thing. But in my case I can't create any deeper route like catalog/add, it excluded from the layout. Any idea?

Comment: In Express 4.x doesn't '/catalog' automatically get treated the same at '/catalog/' anway? See 'Strict routing' - http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set

Comment: @AshleyB it doesn't matter anymore, my problem is my deeper level route can't include the layout :(

Comment: Can you update your answer with the structure of your app (files/folders layout)?

Comment: Are you sure you're adding the routes in the right order? Order matters, you have to add `/catalog/something` ***before*** `/catalog/` etc. otherwise you'll never reach the longer URL's

Comment: @AshleyB - you're right, non-strict routing is now built in, and enabled by default, or in other words, `/catalog` and `/catalog/` should both match the route by default in later versions of Node.

Comment: @AshleyB I can load the view correctly just that it excluded from the layout.